# Using std::wcin to read wchar_t always gives LF (10, 0xA)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, user-input, cin

I use this code in MSVC++2010 to implement a user input loop:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) 
{
    vector<wstring> arguments;
    wstring userinput;
    wchar_t userabort;
    do
    {
        wcout << L"Please type param #" << argc++ << L":" << endl;
        wcin >> userinput;
        arguments.push_back(userinput);
        userinput.clear();
        wcout << L"Type 'y' to input next param, 'n' to start program:" << endl;
        wcin >> userabort;
        wcout << L"Userabort: " << userabort << " (" << int(userabort) << ")" << endl;
    }
    while (userabort == L'y' || userabort == L'Y'
        || userabort == L'j' || userabort == L'J');
    return 1;
}
```

In one of my projects, this works flawlessly (in both Debug and Release configuration). In another of my projects, this very same code (also as only code in `wmain`) behaves strangely (also in both configurations): it does not stop to wait for my input after the "Type 'y' to input next param", but instead immediately reads a linefeed char from the stream.

I even tried `wcin >> skipws >> userabort;` but same result. I don't know what could cause that at all. Could it be the result of some compiler setting or imported file? Or is it maybe the result of pressing *return* to send the `userinput` wstring to the program? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior appears to occur when the "Treat `wchar_t` as a built-in type" (`/Zc:wchar_t`) option is not specified.

Go to the project's properties, under Configuration Properties, C/C++, Language, and make sure that "Treat WChar_t As Built in Type" is set to yes.

This is because when the option is set to no, `wchar_t` becomes a `typedef` for `unsigned short`, which means you can no longer overload on it. As a result the expression `wcin >> userabort` invoked the `operator>>` for `unsigned short` rather than the one for `wchar_t`, which doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: @Felix I think I figured it out. It has to do with how overload resolution is done on `operator>>`. I added the info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation for why this code would work in one program but fail in another. It looks wrong to me. I think you are misunderstanding what `wcin.clear();` does. I guess you are thinking that clears any pending input from the stream, but it doesn't. The way to do that is this mouthful of code

```
wcin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

You would need to `#include <limits>` to get `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: I added `clear()` to look into this error, just for a test. It worked without it as well in one project, and didn't in another. I removed it from my code now to make it more readable as it really makes no difference. Sorry that it puts your remark somewhat out of context. Thanks for the answer though, I will look into the meaning of `clear()` on input streams.